# DNS Server - 2 Domains - 2 DNS Servers - Replicate DNS between two domains in 1 LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, dns-zone

We have 2 DOMAINS  (x.local and y.local) with both own AD and DNS environment.

How can I link the DNS lookup zones from both DNS servers to eachother. So when a client from one domain can resolve DNS names from the other domain withouth manually have to add A-records from both DNS/domains in the Forward Lookup Zone.

Both DNS servers have IP connectivity with eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

Option 1: You can create secondary zones. On the server that hosts x.local you would create a secondary zone for y.local then repeat the other way round. if you do this then you will have to allow Zone transfer from one zone to the other from the zone transfer tab

Option 2: you can create a stub zone on each. On the server that hosts x.local you would create a stub zone for y.local then repeat the other way round adding a stub zone for x.local on the server that hosts y.local

Option 3: you can create conditional forwarders on each. so on the server that hosts x.local you can create a conditional forwarder for y.local then repeat for the server that holds y.local

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831667(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you give me reasons to choose for certain options? For now I have created a Stub Zone and I had to enable Zone transfer for this option to, that correct?

Comment: you shouldn't have to enable Zone Transfer for a stub zone but you do for secondary zones. Conditional Forwarders are easier to set up and don't generate any traffic on their owe but if the NS servers change you have to manually update your conditional forwarders, whereas Stub zones do contact their master (every 15mis be default) to get a list of updated NS records. these records wont change that often but as new NS records are added your Stub zone will be kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Set up conditional forwarders from each domain to the other.